# Angularjs input not working on IE 9/8

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

This code seems to work on all other browsers apart from IE 9 and 8 - can anyone say why this is?

Instead of picking up the value that the user inputs into the text field, it ignores the model and inputs the value I have put in the controller.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="input.value" ng-disabled="input.disabled"/>
<a ng-show="input.button" ng-click="saveInput(input.value)" class="button">Submit value</a>
```

Function:

```
$scope.input.value = 0;
    $scope.saveInput = function(val){
                var url = $scope.apiServer +
                '/user/pushValue?user=' + userID +
                '&month=' + prevMonth + '&value=' + val;
                $http.jsonp(url + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
                    .success(function (data) {
                        $scope.input.confirm = 'Great! Your answer of ' + val + ' has been submitted for' + prevMonthLong;
                    })
            }
```

Comment: have you  got any error? please checkout it on IE console window.

Answer (score 1):

Just globally  define the `$scope.input={}` object in your controller.

like

```
**$scope.input={};**
$scope.input.value = 0;
    $scope.saveInput = function(val){
                var url = $scope.apiServer +
                '/user/pushValue?user=' + userID +
                '&month=' + prevMonth + '&value=' + val;
                $http.jsonp(url + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
                    .success(function (data) {
                        $scope.input.confirm = 'Great! Your answer of ' + val + ' has been submitted for' + prevMonthLong;
                    })
            }
```

Please let me know, if you got any error on IE console window.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, and I am not getting any error logs in the console. It looks like the browser is ignoring the updated model and is just parsing through the original value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your **HTML**

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="input.value" ng-disabled="input.disabled"/>
    <a ng-show="input.button" ng-click="input.saveInput(input.value)" 
class="button">Submit value</a>
```

Your Controller looks like

```
    var input ={value : 0};
     input.saveInput = function(val){
                    var url = $scope.apiServer +
                    '/user/pushValue?user=' + userID +
                    '&month=' + prevMonth + '&value=' + val;
                    $http.jsonp(url + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
                        .success(function (data) {
                            input.confirm = 'Great! Your answer of ' + val + ' has been submitted for' + prevMonthLong;
                        })
                }
$scope.input=input;
```

I also encourage to you to use object literal in controller, not everything bind with $scope. So first create an object and at the end of your controller , you can bind it $scope. Its good practice.